i nead help to update ubuntu do to mistake i did by uninstalling program app, this is what i get in terminal
i nead help to update ubuntu do to mistake i did by uninstalling program app, this is what i get in terminal
[sudo] password for bjarnirt: 
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
 
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [21,0 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
bjarnirt@bjarnirt-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-14IWL:~$ 


This question is similar to: Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
